# Windows 8 phone app - How to add "share app" button?

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, share

I have an app, and I'd like to add a share button to it. Once the button is clicked, I'd like it to open the following window:

[image]

Then the user will choose where to share it and it will display the following default message:

> "Just found this great app! Find it here:http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/amtrak/c8824bb8-3a85-48f7-af54-954bd5673cc6"

Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want [`Task`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19108746/2998271) as in [Microsoft.Phone.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) namespace. And which `Task` to choose is depending on what kind of information you want to share :

- Media file. [`how to use ShareMediaTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- Link/URL. [`how to use ShareLinkTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- Status. [`how to use ShareStatusTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: seeing the question again, I think it is `ShareLinkTask` that you are looking for